# C# & ASP.NET MVC authentication with DOD certificates in IIS local desktop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to add the DOD root certs to my local IIS server so I can authenticate?

I've download them to my local machine via https://militarycac.com/dodcerts.htm install root program, but I cannot figure out how to add them to my Server Certificates in IIS screen so I can bind to them?

[image]

I know the chain has to be setup for it to work correctly as well.

Here is the website error:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You have _Import..._ action on right panel in the **Server Certificates** screen. Did you try to import your certificate?

Comment: @Jackdaw: I don't have access to the pfx. I guess I need to get that from somewhere, but not sure I can obtain one just for a local development box for testing (if this makes sense). I guess that is one of my questions if this is even possible for DOD certs with testing?

Comment: The DoD certificates are not *server* certificates, they are trusted CA certificates. I don't know IIS but there should be a 'trusted roots' or 'Certificate Authorities' or some such store.

Comment: The actual logic used by IIS Manager to query valid Server Certificates can be found in https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/v13.0.23.0/JexusManager.Features.Certificates/CertificatesFeature.cs#L264 So, unless you get such a valid certificate, you cannot bind it to IIS sites.

Comment: Open IIS Manager, click the server name. Double-click Server Certificate. Click Import under the Actions pane. Browse to the DoD certificate location, select it, and click OK. Click on the site that requires a certificate. Select Binding under the Actions pane. Click the binding that requires a certificate and select Edit, or add a site binding for HTTPS. Assign the certificate to the website by selecting the certificate in the SSL Certificate drop-down list and clicking OK.

Comment: @YurongDai: I don't have the .pfx file though. I just have the .cert in my local store that I used that install root app to place there for me?

Comment: I don't know your DOD certificate. But generally speaking, to install an SSL certificate on an IIS server, first contact your certificate authority, create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) in IIS and submit it to the certificate authority. After the certificate is issued, download the certificate and save it locally. Then click "Complete Certificate Request" in the IIS Certificate module to import the certificate. Reference link: https://thesecmaster.com/step-by-step-procedure-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-the-iis-server/